# Dúvida com validação de login

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um site para meu TCC, e nele tento fazer um sistema de login com validação de usuário por níveis.

Vamos supor se o usuário é administrador, ao logar ele irá verificar no bd se usuário logado vai ter o campo "tipo" != 2; se caso não ele irá para tela de usuário normal.

Segue abaixo o código que desenvolvi em php, porém está apresentando erro após tentar validar, ele vai para uma página em branco;

```
    <?php
include("conexao.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
/* Verifica se existe usuario, o segredo ta aqui quando ele procupa uma 
linha q contenha o login e a senha digitada */
$sql_logar = "SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE email = '$email' && senha = '$senha'";
$exe_logar = mysqli_query($conection, $sql_logar) or die (mysqli_error());
$fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);
$num_logar = mysqli_num_rows($exe_logar);

//Verifica se n existe uma linha com o login e a senha digitado
if ($num_logar == 0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Login ou senha incorreto!</div>";
    header("Location: index.php?login");
} 
else{
   //Cria a sessão e verifica tipo de login
    session_start();

    while($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_logar) ){
    $tipo = $percorrer['tipo'];

    if($_SESSION['tipo'] != 2){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
     header("Location: aluno.php");
    }
    }
}
?>
```

O que posso fazer para que a validação com níveis funcione conforme o planejado?

Comment: Pior que não, ele vai para valida.php que é o código acima

Comment: O `session_start();` tem que vir antes de tudo, antes do HTML inclusive, se tiver.

Comment: Eu separei o valida.php do formulário em html com um action="valida.php", mas preciso também colocar o session start antes no php?

Comment: Vc vai colocar o `sessiont_start();` só uma vez após a abertura `<?php`. E também não use `&&`. Use `AND`.

Comment: Fiz o que pediu, mas ainda não deu certo, retornou para o valida.php, acho que o problema está  no while.

Comment: Mas já não está? buguei kkkkkkk

Comment: Deu certo, mas quando é igual a 2 ele não vai para o administrador.php, eu usaria o else ali?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o `session_start();` apenas uma vez no início do bloco:

```
<?php
session_start();
// resto do código
```

Não use o operador `&&` no MySQL, e sim o `AND` ([ver documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)).

Problema:

Coloque o `if` após o `while`, só que no `if` você está comparando uma `SESSION` que aparentemente não existe. Você deveria comparar a variável `$tipo` que acabara de declarar, e precisa de um `else` caso o `if` não seja atendido:

```
while($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_logar) ){
   $tipo = $percorrer['tipo'];
}

$_SESSION['tipo'] = $tipo;

if($tipo != 2){
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
   header("Location: aluno.php");
}else{
   header("Location: administrador.php");
}
```

As `SESSIONS` `email` e `senha` serão criadas apenas para `$tipo` diferente de 2? Tem que verificar isso. Se for para qualquer caso, teria que ficar assim:

```
while($percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_logar) ){
   $tipo = $percorrer['tipo'];
}

$_SESSION['tipo'] = $tipo;
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;

if($tipo != 2){
   header("Location: aluno.php");
}else{
   header("Location: administrador.php");
}
```

Outra coisa, remova a linha `$fet_logar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe_logar);` senão o `$percorrer = mysqli_fetch_array($exe_logar)` do `while` vai estar vazio e o `$tipo` não vai ter nenhum valor.

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções @Sam, funcionou certinho, porém quando o usuário tem o tipo = 2; ele não leva para o administrador.php, ambos == 2, e != 2; leva ao aluno.php. O que posso fazer?

Comment: Ainda não deu certo, tentei substituir o != por ==, e ele leva apenas para o administrador, já o != apenas para o aluno :/, mesmo alterando no bd entre o tipo 1 e 2 do usuário.

Comment: Ele aparece Notice: Undefined variable: tipo; nas linha onde tem o $_SESSION, o if, e no while.